# Howto configure Raid on IBM x3500 m3

Tags: configuration, ibm

I have recently acquired an old IBM x3500 m3 and I'm struggling to find the raid configuration. I've checked out everything in the uefi and post doesn't show any key combinations to access ServeRaid. I've disabled the "show boot logo" setting.

[This guy](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Hardware/Misc/Q_26667634.html) used a boot cd to configure the raid controller. After searching i found a [ServeRaid Support CD](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-64669) that might do the trick. I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Does anybody know how to do this ?

As a bonus question, the server has 6 250 GB drives but i only see 2 virtual drives.
That leaves me with the assumption one of the virtual drives might be a Raid 10 (or they are not configured at all). Is it possible to grow to a Raid 5 (or 6) without data loss ?

Since it's just a lab setup data loss would not be to tragic but I would not mind if I could skip reinstalling the system.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the boot CD seems to be the only possibility.

Download the IBM ServeRaid Support CD form [here](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-64669).
Boot from the CD and hit ctrl + m.

Raid migration eg. from Raid 1 to 5 is possible.

The raid configuration was 3x Raid 1 with one degraded array.